# How can I remove elements in a list which elements are read from a .txt file using Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, file

I'm doing a simple task manager program. The tasks are added to a list and saved in a .txt file so that they can be still being able to be managed (added/removed from the list) the next time the program is opened. Nevertheless, while testing the program, I figured out that when I try to remove an element from the list, the terminal closes suddenly.

The .txt file is saved everytime the terminal is closed from the program's menu option. Moreover, the first time the program is executed, it search if the .txt file exists: if it doesn't, the program just runs; if it already exists, Python read the .txt file and add the elements from it to the list.

I'm learning programming by self-teaching since a few weeks before starting the career, so I'll appreciate your help so much. I have more bugs, but just wanna ask for that one.

Here is the program, you can just copy it and run it in your computer if you want:

```
# TASK MANAGER v0.2 ENGLISH VERSION

import os

margin = " " * 5   # Just a margin in order to clear the terminal on the print() functions. It's just esthetic.


## TASKS LIST. This is the list in which the user adds or remove elements
tasks = []   


## METHODS

def add_task():   # Adds an element to the var: tasks
    return tasks.append(input('NEW TASK: '))

def remove_task():   # Removes an element from the var: tasks
    return tasks.remove(input('REMOVE TASK: '))

def credits():   # Shows the credits
    os.system('cls')
    print(margin + 'TaskManager version 0.2, created by Vicente Pascual Llinares in 05/2023.')
    print(margin + 'In this version, tasks are showed in a list above of the terminal.')
    print(margin + 'You can add and remove any number of elements to the task list.')
    print(margin + 'What is new compared to v0.1 is that tasks are now saved everytime you close de program from the menu.')
    print('')
    input(margin + 'Press ENTER to go back to menu.')

def bugs():   # Shows the bugs
    os.system('cls')
    print(margin + 'BUGS:')
    print('')
    print(margin + 'BUGS:')
    print(margin + '* If an integer isn\'t wrote on the menu, the program closes suddenly.')
    print(margin + '* The program closes by pressing ENTER when it isn\'t expecting that key to be pressed.')
    print(margin + '* When an element is wrote to be removed -in 2) Remove task- from list, the program closes suddenly')
    print()
    input(margin + 'Press ENTER to go back to menu.')

def program():    # Runs the program itself
    start = True
    while start == True:
        print(margin + '####################')
        print(margin + '### TASK MANAGER ###')
        print(margin + '####### v0.2 #######')
        print('')
        print(margin + 'Tasks: ')
        print('')
        for i in tasks:   # Prints the tasks list elements on the terminal
            print(i)
        print()
        print(margin + '--------------------')
        print()

        # This is just a menu
        menu = int(input(margin + '1) Add task\n%s2) Remove task\n\n%s3) CREDITS\n%s4) BUGS\n\n%s5) CLOSE\n\n'%(margin, margin, margin, margin)))

        if menu == 1:
            add_task()
        elif menu == 2:
            remove_task()
        elif menu == 3:
            credits()
        elif menu == 4:
            bugs()
        elif menu == 5:   # Before the program closes, writes an .txt file in order to save the tasks list for a future running of the program.
            open('task_list.txt', 'w')
            for i in tasks:
                with open('task_list.txt', 'a') as f:
                    f.write(i + '\n')
            start = False
        else:
            print(margin + 'Selcet one of the options writing one of the numbers avaibles.')
            input(margin + 'Press ENTER to go back to menu.')

        os.system('cls')   # This manteins the terminal cleaned.
            

## OPENING. 

try:   # Here, Python discovers if already exist a .txt where takes the elements for the list 'tasks'
    file = open('task_list.txt', 'r')
    text = file.read()
    tasks = text.split(',')
    program()
     

except FileNotFoundError:   # If that .txt file doesn't exist, it just run the program itself.
    program()
```

When the program doesn't use the .txt file, it works right. But I want to have a save option in order no to lose the tasks I've added once, as well as being able to add or remove any element (task) to/from the list.

Comment: On its own, `open('task_list.txt', 'w')` doesn't do anything. Why not use `with` on that line?

Comment: Also, rather than read back and forth to a list and file, you might want to try sqlite module instead

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'll learn about sqlite module then, thanks a lot! In fact, I'll start the IA engineering in a few months and I wanna know some programming basic skills, so your recommendation helps me for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because in try block you are using `tasks = text.split(',')` it uses "," as a delimiter, meanwhile you are using "\n" as a delimiter here `f.write(i + "\n")` when you are writing the tasks inside the .txt file. so when the program runs it doesn't save the tasks inside the file to the tasks= [ ] list. and when you enter the task to remove from the list it gives you a "ValueError" and the program stops.
first of all, use "w" instead of "a" when you are writing the tasks in .txt file because "a" is for append and it will duplicate the tasks in .txt file.

```
with open("task_list.txt", "w") as f:
                for i in tasks:  #
                    f.write(i + "\n")
```

and then use f.readlines instead and then use a list comprehension to save the tasks in tasks [ ]

```
try:
    f = open("task_list.txt", "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    tasks = [line.strip() for line in lines]  # Remove newline characters from each line
    program()
```

Now you can easily remove the tasks from the list and write them again in the txt file instead of appending it and creating duplicates.